# Violation of primary key when the values aren't the same

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have the following data in my DB:

[image]

Notice where the cursor is, so the field has some spaces after the word. And then I'm calling the following code to insert a new value:

```
 var tagList = new List<ProductTag> { new ProductTag { Name = "diepvries" } };
 var sbCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_dataContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString) { BulkCopyTimeout = 60 * 10 };
 sbCopy.WriteToServer(tagList.AsDataReader());
```

However, the following exception is thrown

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.ProductTags'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProductTags'. The duplicate key
>   value is (diepvries).

I also tested with text "diepvries2" and it worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

According to [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626),

> "SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   <Comparison Predicate>, General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. **The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them.**"

Comment: To add a little context with your current situation. "Diepvries      " is equal to "Diepvries"

Answer (score 2):

What kind of DB?
I know that in SQL server, strings are "padded" with white spaces to the same length before comparison. As such, your two strings are identical as far as the SQL database is concerned.
Detail are [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626).